# Сколько вариаций ключа может выдать EC_KEY_generate_key(pkey) из OpenSSL?

Tags: openssl

Собственно вопрос указан в теме. Просто нужно понимать насколько надёжным может быть ключ. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Зависит от выбранной кривой. в описании кривой всегда указана длина ключа. Количество вариантов соответственно 2 в степени длины ключа